# DataTables SSP - Column Issues

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I'm pulling data into DataTables using SSP. My dataset has 70+ columns. I can pull the first 25 columns of the dataset to the table without any issues, but any more than that and it fails. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

TIA

Comment: You must have get a e3rror message, can you post it

Comment: The DataTable definition and a sample of the JSON would also be helpful - i.e. whatever is needed for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The error I'm getting is:

ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED